# How to print a specific element of an array passed via context api?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to a print a specific element of an array based on the user, How do I get that specific element and print it on the screen  ????

```
const state = useContext(GlobalState)
const[ulocations]=useState(state.categoriesAPI.locationapi[0]) 

const [userlist]=useState([{location_id:'5476',name:'John', age:36}])

// ulocations is an ARRAY OF OBJECTS [{...},{...},{...}]

// where an obj contains{_id:'5476',name:'europe'}
  


  const findspecificcountry=()=>{
        
                  for(let i=0;i<ulocations.length;i++){

                    if(ulocations[i]._id==myuserlist[0].location_id){
                       return ulocations[i].name
                          }
                          }

    }



return(

userlist.map(a=>{
<h1> a.name </h1>
<h2>a.age </h2>
<h3> {findspecificcountry()} </h3> // doesnt print the value europe ????? nothing appears 
})

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve your locations from the `GlobalState` context, you would do so with:

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(GlobalState)
const ulocations = state.categoriesAPI.locationapi[0] // Assuming this is your location list
```

It looks like your user list should just be a constant here also. No need for the `useState` hook:

```
const userlist = [{location_id:'5476',name:'John', age:36}]
```

When you map over your `userlist`, you can then pass the user's location ID to your function:

```
userlist.map(a => {
  ...
  <h3> {findspecificcountry(a.location_id)}</h3>
})
```

The function would then accept that location parameter:

```
const findspecificcountry = (id) => {}
```

I don't know the format of your API data, so I leave updating the function to you.